# ArcGIS 10 add-in: ComboBox add-in component focus issue

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, add-in

**Update 9/9/11:** Here is a minimal example project that will reproduce the issue for me (VS 2008 solution): http://wfurl.com/09061bf

I have an ArcMap 10 add-in with a [`ComboBox`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001v00000173000000) class that I place on a toolbar. When I attempt to display a `MessageBox` after the user submits a value by typing in the ComboBox and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the ComboBox steals the keyboard focus from the MessageBox, so when the user tries to dismiss the MessageBox by pressing Enter again, the ComboBox's `OnEnter` event handler runs again instead of the MessageBox being closed.

Without any checks against this, you might end up with numerous MessageBox instances on top of one another with no way to dismiss them except by clicking OK on each one.

Attempts to work around this behavior have failed and include:

1. Disabling the ComboBox before showing the MessageBox and re-enabling it afterwards. The enabled state doesn't change until after the MessageBox is closed and the focus issue still occurs. Employing `Application.DoEvents` has no effect.
2. Setting a class-level boolean that tells the OnEnter handler to simply return when true (Set to True just before showing the MessageBox and False afterward.) The focus issue remains, meaning it takes 3 Enter keystrokes to dismiss the MessageBox, but at least the OnEnter code doesn't run again.
3. Setting the MessageBox's parent window to the ArcMap application using the `IWin32Window` overload (actually this is necessary to get the MessageBox to show in the middle of the ArcMap window instead of on top of the ComboBox).
4. Explicitly setting the MessageBox's MessageBoxOptions property to 0x1000 (`MB_SYSTEMMODAL`) or 0x2000 (`MB_TASKMODAL`)
5. Using `IApplication.StatusBar.set_Message()` instead of MessageBox. The ComboBox's HintText message, even if not specified, or set to an empty string, instantly overrides anything I write in the set_Message main pane (0), so this method is essentially useless with Addin ComboBoxes.

Anyone have any other ideas as to what else I can try, or must I once again look at a WinAPI solution to deal with the ArcGIS framework's shortcomings?

Comment: What happens if you open a form, rather than a combo box? Or you could just change the `HintText` to your message.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no HintText property on the ComboBox, the only place it can be set (as far as I can tell) is in the Config.esriaddinx XML file. Using a Form has the same problem -- just get a bunch of Form instances instead of MessageBox instances.

Comment: I see. This is a tough one. I wish I had other ideas.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the ideas. I wonder if there is something I can cast the ComboBox to in order to set the HintText/Message. ICommand.Message seems to be read-only.

Comment: Also tried setting ICommandItem.Message but it cannot be set on "built-in" commands which apparently includes add-in commands.

Comment: I came across this when I was having a similar issue - perhaps it can shed some light on your question. It has to do with how you're handling validation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290629/cannot-tab-out-of-databound-winforms-dropdown-list

Comment: Does the combobox really need to be on a toolbar?  Not sure, but this might be a non-issue if the combox were on a dockable window.

Comment: @Radar, this isn't a WinForms ComboBox, so there are no validation events exposed, only OnEnter and OnEditChange. You either update it or you don't based on your own validation routine.

Comment: @Kirk I am sure simply not using the toolbar-based ComboBox would fix it, but IMO it's a problem that needs to be solved not skirted around. I wonder if the ComboBox runs on a separate thread than the main ArcMap GUI thread?

Comment: Yeah, when you make a combobox on a toolbar that is not in an add-in, you need to be sure to use [ICompletionNotify.SetComplete](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00430000002q000000), which gets passed with [IToolControl.Onfocus](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OnFocus_Method/00430000006t000000/).  Unfortunately, I don't see anything analogous to ICompletionNotify that gets passed to add-in comboboxes.

Comment: Added to the OP a minimal VS2008 solution that reproduces the problem for me. Hopefully someone more creative than myself can figure out how to make the MessageBox disappear when you hit Enter after it appears. For me it just stacks up MessageBoxes each time you hit enter.

Comment: It gets worse.. the toolbar and combobox are not standard Windows controls but a third party libray, from the window class it looks like CodeJock CommandBars for C++. Even getting the window handle is problematic, not to mention controlling the combobox via API calls, which result mostly in non-standard windows messages. Other than using the good old tool control, the only option I see is to intercept windows messages from this control and check for Enter key yourself...

Comment: Yeesh -- I wondered why add-in ComboBoxes looked different from the built-in ones. Thank you for your insights.

Comment: Have you tried spawning the MessageBox on a different thread? Or does this box need to be executed inline with the ComboBox code?

Comment: I have not, not sure how exactly but I'll look into it. I was thinking the opposite though. If they were on the same thread wouldn't the ComboBox not be able to respond to events and steal focus in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code that you gave as an example. In my testing this worked for me.

```
new Thread(() =>
{
   MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The value '{0}' is not an integer!", currentValue));
}).Start();
```

**Edit** To incorporate the great comments, and as Petr pointed out that this way may be dangerous here is the other way of doing this as well:

```
SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(_ => MessageBox.Show("Message"), null);
```

Thanks to Kirk and Petr for this!

Comment: As it does for me too, nicely done!

Comment: Awesome! I wish I knew more technical details of why this works better, but I bet it is how threads and messages are handled in ArcMap. Oh well, another quirk for ESRI that we have to work around.

Comment: This will work for message boxes (sort of - they are not modal, the user can still interact with ArcMap window while the message box is open), but be warned that many scenarios, like opening a new form, need to be performed from the main thread.

Comment: @petr I wonder this [SynchronizationContext.Post trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457237/run-code-on-ui-thread-without-control-object-present/505361#505361) might work to overcome this.

Comment: @Kirk, good one, I just tested this, calling `SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(_ => MessageBox.Show("Message"), null);` and works great - it does execute the delegate on the main UI thread, so the message box behaves correctly as a modal window. Should work for more complex UI related tasks as well.

Comment: @Kirk & Peter, you are right, it doesn't behave modally when put on its own thread. The Post trick works great. I'd rep you all if I could, high fives all around :)

Comment: Bonus: Executing `ArcMap.Application.StatusBar.set_Message` using the Post method also works -- I guess ArcMap doesn't take it if it's not executed on the UI thread.

Comment: Addendum to the Bonus: But depending on how long your thread runs, you might need to use `SynchronizationContext.Current.Send` to run `Application.DoEvents` before setting the StatusBar message using Post *after* the UI thread sets it based on your mouse cursor being inside the ComboBox.

Comment: Addendum to the Addendum: Or just do `Application.DoEvents` in the same delegate you are `Post`'ing.